# Show Bootstrap modal without using .modal("show")

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

When I try using `$("#modalPlaced").modal("show")` I get an error of `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).modal is not a function`

But jQuery is properly loaded as this code works properly:

```
$.ajax({
  url: form.action,
  data: $(form).serialize(),
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (data) => {
    if (data.message === 'Success!') {
      $("[data-dismiss=modal]").trigger({type: "click"});
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to show the modal with the id of `modalPlaced`? 
Or how can I fix my `.modal is not a function` error?

Comment: did you include all the bootstrap required JS libraries?

Comment: @ochi good call. I'm using React, so I have `import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap' `. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you have not included the js file.
try adding the following to the head tag on your page:

`<script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The following works.  Can you please tell if this works for you?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>IndexStackOverflow102</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#modalPlaced").modal('show');

        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="modalPlaced" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Popup</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```